# What does a tripple point expression mean?

Tags: flutter, dart

What does the tripple point expression mean?

```
Column(
  children: [
    Text('Header'),
    ...List.generate( // what does it mean?
      question.options.length,
      (index) => SizedBox(height: index),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a spread operator. You can read about it [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator).

Simply it makes code smaller and easy to read. Here is the analog of the code above:

```
final children = <Widget>[
    Text('Header'),
];
children.addAll(List.generate( 
      question.options.length,
      (index) => SizedBox(height: index),
    ));
Column(
  children: children,
),
```

The spread operator adds all values from the list to another list.